# How do I make a responsive box size

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to make this work and I tried everything I know so far. My goal with the code is to have the div BOX as the container and when the window resizes, the content is still inside the BOX container. Here is the code.

What happens is when I resize the window, the box appears to be smaller and it overflows outside the box.
this is the CSS part of the code, I think it might be on my settings but I don't know where it is

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 2%;
}

#BOX {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(199, 249, 255, 0.8);
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 3rem 3rem 5rem 3rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

#loginForm {
  left: 0px;
}

#registerForm {
  left: 500px;
  top: -245px;
  opacity: 00;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="BOX">
    <h1 id="transitionOL">WELCOME</h1>
    <div class="toggle" id="toggle">
      <button class="login" id="LOGIN">LOGIN</button><button class="login" id="SIGNUP">SIGNUP</button>
    </div>
    <div id="FORMS">
      <form action="" id="loginForm">
        <ul>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px; margin-top: 105px; padding: 3px;"><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="USERNAME" class="input"></li>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px"><input type="Password" ; placeholder="Password" id="PASSWORD" class="input"></li>
          <hr style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
          <li><button class="login1" id="RDbtn1" onclick="">LOGIN</button></li>
        </ul>
      </form>
      <form action="" id="registerForm">
        <ul>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px;"><input type="text"  placeholder="Username" id="USERNAME" class="input"></li>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px;"><input type="Password" placeholder="Password" id="PASSWORD" class="input"></li>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px;"><input type="Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="PASSWORD" class="input"></li>
          <li style="margin-bottom:45px"><input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="E-mail" class="input"></li>
          <hr style="margin-bottom: 10px; ">
          <li>
            <li><button class="login1" id="RDbtn" onclick="">SIGNUP</button></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are there `;` in the `input` tags?

Comment: my bad, it's just a habit I got from java. I'll remove it. sorry.

Comment: So, you want the container in the centre, right? Which does not scale on viewport size change.

Comment: well that's one thing, but at the same time, when I resize the container (the div with an ID of BOX), the forms are not inside of it and it's overflowing outside.

Comment: If the screen will be small then the elements have only two options.                                 
 1) It overflows                                       2) It's size and alignment changes and nothing overflows.

Comment: How can I make the alignment change and nothing overflows? I can't inherit the size because the forms are shifted downwards.

Comment: Why are you using inline styles? It makes it hard to work and create additional bugs. Also, It has a higher priority over others

Comment: im using relative and absolute positioning, if that's what you're asking. I have yet to learn the inline styles